# Apache, importing a python module with mutex and ladon, script hang

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, ladon

i have a strange behaviour of a python script running through Apache/mod_wsgi/Ladon, when running it from a python shell, every thing is fine, on one machine everything is fine, but on the other the same script hang and it seems that it is indefinitely doing or waiting something: that is opening the page from 192.168.xxx.xxx/ws/ never end (browser are loading again and again, turning round, ie saying ). I can not find what happen, logging thing to the apache log show me nothing as the script imported seems to never end when used through apache/ladon. (and as both machines are configured the same way, i have plain headache with that :/)

as the script load some data from the filesystem and database, can the hanging be from locking these ressources indefinitely?

can i wrap the module that hang inside something like the lines below to be sure there is nothing locking? actually i have tried to do so, and it change nothing at all, but and this is my first question, is it right to write it like this (as i am a bit confued but different mutex processes)?

```
[...]
from multiprocessing import Lock
mutex = Lock()

mutex.acquire()
import MyHangingModule
mutex.release()
[...]
```

is there any case where when serving a page from apache may end with an infinite time out? that is the python mod_wsgi/ladon script is killed by apache or ladon while something is still waiting for a reply from the killed? as when shutting down the server i get some:

```
[Tue Jul 09 16:07:47 2013] [warn] child process 1676 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Jul 09 16:07:49 2013] [warn] child process 1676 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Jul 09 16:07:51 2013] [warn] child process 1676 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Jul 09 16:07:53 2013] [error] child process 1676 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Tue Jul 09 16:07:54 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

(by searching about pid, through mod_status, it is actually the handing script staying in W mode)

EDIT: about wsgi, i have nothing Inside the wsgi.conf, everything is commented # actually, I install it from the default Debian installation. Is there something that i should look? or that I obviously miss?

for the other, it is also default Debian (actually no change inside config file, but specifically install apache2-mpm-worker):

```
# worker MPM
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Output of `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -l`

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  worker.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

about mod for wsgi (without adding `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`) to `wsgi.conf`):

```
<pre>
mod_wsgi.process_group = ['']
mod_wsgi.application_group = ['myserver|/mycfg'] # mycfg is actually the name of the python script while i have replaced the server name for posting here
wsgi.multithread = [True]
</pre>
```

about mod for wsgi (after adding `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`) to `wsgi.conf`) (thus very slow for my others scripts):

```
<pre>
mod_wsgi.process_group = ['']
mod_wsgi.application_group = ['']
wsgi.multithread = [True]
</pre>
```

well, if it could help, here is the log part for a sessing using a webservice that may be slow :
(actually i would have liked that the `externalDataLoader.py loaded: 0:00:00.394606 (21941 entries loaded) was shared by every one and then occurs only one. Also i have deactivate all others python handled... can this be that the two`mod_wsgi (pid=xxxxx): Attach interpreter ''`can then be using some ressources and waiting indefinetly without any response and thus making the whole server and others WS query to end with the "child process not exit" ?

```
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:20 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:21 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=11199): Initializing Python.
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:21 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:21 2013] [info] Server built: Mar  3 2013 11:36:06
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:21 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=11203): Initializing Python.
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:21 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=11199): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:21 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=11203): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:39 2013] [info] [client 192.168.1.130] mod_wsgi (pid=11199, process='', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/mywebserver/ws/wshandler.py'., referer: http://192.168.1.5/demo/search.html
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:40 2013] [error] externalDataLoader.py loaded: 0:00:00.394606 (21941 entries loaded)
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:42 2013] [error] WSforSearchInsideExternalData. loaded: 0:00:00.000032.
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:42 2013] [error] searched [test] in [External1]: 0:00:00.026233
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:42 2013] [error] searched [test] in [External2]: 0:00:00.067869
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:43 2013] [error] searched [test] in [External3]: 0:00:00.104222
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:43 2013] [error] searching done for [test]: 0:00:00.104222
[Wed Jul 24 10:49:59 2013] [info] [client 192.168.1.130] mod_wsgi (pid=11203, process='', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/mywebserver/ws/wshandler.py'., referer: http://192.168.1.5/demo/search.html
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:00 2013] [error] externalDataLoader.py loaded: 0:00:00.384349 (21941 entries loaded)
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:02 2013] [error] WSforSearchInsideExternalData. loaded: 0:00:00.000033.
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:02 2013] [error] searched [abjg] in [External1]: 0:00:00.026000
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:02 2013] [error] searched [abjg] in [External2]: 0:00:00.066215
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:02 2013] [error] searched [abjg] in [External3]: 0:00:00.100293
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:02 2013] [error] searching done for [abjg]: 0:00:00.100293
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:40 2013] [error] searched [abjg] in [External1]: 0:00:00.001513
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:40 2013] [error] searched [abjg] in [External2]: 0:00:00.080266
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:40 2013] [error] searched [abjg] in [External3]: 0:00:00.119280
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:40 2013] [error] searching done for [abjg]: 0:00:00.119280
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:48 2013] [error] searched [abje] in [External1]: 0:00:00.001491
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:48 2013] [error] searched [abje] in [External2]: 0:00:00.079586
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:48 2013] [error] searched [abje] in [External3]: 0:00:00.123212
[Wed Jul 24 10:50:48 2013] [error] searching done for [abje]: 0:00:00.123212
```

Answer (score 1):

See and try the solution described in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

You are likely using an extension module which will not work in a sub interpreter.

In short, add to the Apache configuration:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: well, yes it allow the script to work on the machine where it did not before. BTW everything is now very very slow, is there any reason for that? and also i still not get the point on why it do work on the other machine - same script, same required modules -without this directive?

Comment: General slowness can be due to many reasons. It can be because of a mis configured Apache, or could be your application code. You would need to supply details of Apache MPM settings and mod_wsgi configuration for the first. For the latter you should look at performance monitoring tools to work it out.

Comment: hello, edit to add missing informations. Best regards and thank you for your help :)

Comment: Linux systems don't usually default to worker MPM, so I am not sure your MPM settings are necessarily the correct ones. You also don't say how you have configured mod_wsgi and in particular whether you are using daemon mode. For how to work out MPM see http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Apache_Build_Information

Comment: i have done nothing about WSGI. the wsgi.conf files contained only commented stuff. I have edit to output data according to the link you provide kindly. So i think am in Embedded mode, even if i do not really understand what it may imply. EDIT: the post i have made are because i have reverted to not using `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` due to slowlyness. Should i post the same after i add it again ?

Comment: You still haven't indicated how you have configured mod_wsgi. What is the actual WSGIScriptAlias directive, or other means you are using to specify what the WSGI application is, that you are using?

Comment: ok, i have asked here. so it looks like it is `WSGIScriptAlias /ws "/var/www/mywebserver/ws/wshandler.py` and something calling Ladon is used. Is it what you were asking?

Comment: You said that application group was coming out as 'myserver|/mycfg'. That doesn't match what you just said. If mounted at '/ws', then that should be in the application group name and not '/mycfg'.

Comment: Suggest you ensure that you have LogLevel set to info in Apache and then look at the mod_wsgi messages to ensure that your code is always being loaded into application group where name logged is empty string.

Comment: ok sorry. for answering your question i made a script that provide the datas about configuration (see `pre` insiders). For this script i have added `WSGIScriptAlias /mycfg "/var/www/mywebserver/ws/mycfg.wsgi"` but for my application i actually use  `WSGIScriptAlias /ws "/var/www/mywebserver/ws/wshandler.py"`. so what you advice is that i must have application group name always set to empty when using the configuration i describe to avoid any slowlyness ?

Comment: Consider trying to work out whether it is your application or Apache that is the cause by using monitoring software. New Relic has a free tier you can use to try and work it out.

Comment: well trying to analyse it with NewRelic, but for now do not manage to have anything observed... may be the Apache + Ladon mask something to NewRelic. I have added the `import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('/var/www/mywebserver/ws/newrelic.ini')` to the `wshandler.py` whom itself import and include others modules but nothing is send to NR... damned! one step forward, so many back!

Comment: If this is a custom WSGI application and not one supported by New Relic agent, you will need to do https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-integration#wsgi-application If still issues, send an email to support@newrelic.com with details of what you have done and what WSGI framework/application you are running.